# Auto Populate the Company Field During Lead Creation

Tags: apex, process-builder, visual-workflow, before-trigger

I would like to auto populate the Company Name field, during lead creation, based on the Account Name selected from a custom Account Lookup field on the lead object. As soon as the user selects the Account name from the lookup field, the same name is populated in the Company field...

Can this be accomplished with an Apex Trigger, or should Flow/Process Builder be used?

Update:

I tried to setup a process which doesn't have a criteria, but has an immediate action to set the Company field value based on the Account lookup filed value. It doesn't seem to work. Do I need to add a criteria which looks at the value in the company field and if the value is null, populate it with the value in the company field? Agency Name is the label for Account.

See the screen shots attached

[image: Lead Object Start the Process]

[image: No Criteria]

[image: Update the field]

Here's the result I get with Process Builder in place

[image: Enter First & Last Name of New Lead]
[image: Select Agency/Company from lookup Field]
[image: Get Prompt to enter Value in Agency Name/Company Field]

Answer (score 1):

I think you are being downvoted because usually you come with a proposed solution already built and then someone is able to help you correct any problems you are having with what you have tried.

to answer your question:
This is do-able through both a trigger and a process builder assuming that the field can be updated after the record is saved.

if you need the realtime updation, you will need to create a custom lightning component or visual force page.

Edit: my try

[image]

[image]

[image]

After activating the process builder, i edited and saved a contact record without changing anything and the hold acc name was updated (but im actually using account number or something)

[image]

edit 2: just tried with account name -- success
[image]

Comment: Hi Tim. I am a newb to the site and Ape Triggers. I tried to setup a process which doesn't have a criteria, but has an immediate action to set the Company field value based on the Account lookup filed value. It doesn't seem to work. Do I need to add a criteria which looks at the value in the company field and if the value is null, populate it with the value in the company field?

Comment: Hi, the logic sounds okay but may be of some use to update your main post with what you have tried with screenshots and then I, or some other user can look at what you have tried and help you from there.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance Tim. I updated the question.

Comment: Okay, so I followed the steps you placed and have found success. dumb question. did you activate the process builder? because i basically built what you built except from contact to account grabbing account number and it works fine.

Comment: Interesting... Great question, though the process is active. Here are my steps: I click create to create a new lead, enter the lead's first and last name, then select the agency from the lookup field. nothing gets populated in the company field. I click save and is prompted to enter the agency name; API name Company...

Comment: Tim, is that a workflow rule in your screenshot used to check the process builder OR the actual workflow used to get the result?

Comment: Thats the actual workflow used to get the result im posting -- edit: and i just tried my flow with a new contact and it works as well, you can also do this through a trigger, although a process builder is better

Comment: I'm confused... You mention flow and process builder. Are you able to post screen shots of your process builder similar to mine? I think I need an evaluation criteria in my process builder to check if the company name field is blank  and the lookup field has a value, when the new lead is created. then put the lookup filed value in the company name field... Thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, I use flow and process builder interchangeable and its confusing. all of my logic is present in the screenshots above, which is a process builder.

Comment: I'm blind... I swear. Beating my head on my desk. Lol!

Comment: this only works after you save, you need to disable your validation rule

Comment: I select the value from the lookup filed, the company field is blank. I click save to save the new lead and is immediately prompted to enter a value in the company field. I event tried Agency Name (API Name is Company) -- Field Reference -- Agency__c... Received the same prompt to enter a value in the Agency Name Field... No validation rules are in place.

Comment: you have something else going on here. a process builder won't create a prompt for you to enter your a field. my guess is a validation rule or trigger. I would suggest creating a playground account and recreating your test.

Comment: It's not Process Builderthats' prompting for the filed to be populated. When I create the new lead and the Company field (Required) is blank, I get the prompt. Process Builder isn't updating the Company Name for the New Lead being created, with the value in the lookup field.

Comment: I just added the screen shots of the prompt I get when creating the new lead...

Answer (score 0):

Because `Lead.Company` is a required field, it must exist before the Lead is saved. Process Builder (which would call Flow) can only execute after the record passes validation rules and required field checks)

as such, you have two options (or at least two straightforward ones)

- Use an Apex before insert trigger to copy over the value referenced by Lead.Account__c (i.e. `Lead.Account__r.Name`) to Lead.Company. If you are new to triggers, go to Trailhead to get you started.
- Wait for Spring 20 wherein [auto-launched flows can execute before a record is saved](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder.htm) to enhance data on the record to-be-saved.

Comment: Thanks Cropredy! Trailhead here I come! I need a refresher on Apex Triggers anyway. Plus I'll learn more this way.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, it can be done by Enabling Person Accounts, which allow the Company field to be optional. Keep in mind it cannot be disabled afterwards and it will consume more storage.

It can be done this way ([from original docs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.emergency_response_admin_enable_person_accounts.htm&type=5)):

1. From Setup, enter Person Accounts in the Quick Find box, and then select Person Accounts.
2. Go through the steps listed on the Setup page.
3. Turn on Person Accounts.
4. After Person Accounts is enabled, a person account record type is created. You can create additional record types for person account if needed.
5. To begin using person accounts in Health Cloud, from Setup, enter Custom Settings in the Quick Find box, then select Custom Settings.
6. In the list of custom settings, click Manage next to the Use Person Accounts custom setting.
7. Click Edit next to Use Person Account and select Enable.
8. Assign the person account record type to user profiles and the system administrator profile.

Alternatively, since Record-triggered Flows can now run before the actual record is saved (through the Fast Field Updates option), and Process Builders are going to be phased out soon, auto-populating the Company field can be done through the Flow Builder without creating useless Person Accounts.